# Firestore @ Android - listener is lagging on app resume

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using FireStore (Not Firebase Realtime Database) on an Android app.

When the app loads, I am adding a listener to a collection (See code below)

The listener is working very well and is updating correctly as long as the app is active.

However, after the app goes to the background, ***when resuming the app the listener sometimes has a lag of about 60-90 seconds until it updates with changes from the server***. If I close the app and restart it, it updates instantly.

When the app stops, I detach the listener, and I resume it OnResume. I tried also without detaching the listener, but I am experiencing the same problem.

Does anyone know how to solve it? See code below:

***Listener (Being initialized OnResume):***

```
m_registration = db.collection('names').
        orderBy("stamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
 
                        }
```

On stop, I am detaching the listener:

```
m_registration.remove();
```

Comment: While the app is background, is your app somehow losing internet connectivity?

Comment: It's hard to say, maybe for a few seconds. When using a mobile phone, obviously you don't have reception wherever you go. I am guessing that basically you are asking whether the socket gets disconnected? Assuming that yes, why does it take so much to reconnect OnResume? On appose to the app startup?

Comment: But in your case, before those 60-90 seconds until it updates is there any possibility to have a disconnection?

Comment: Are you getting such a message `Failed to resolve name. status={1}` in the logcat? Can you please check?

Comment: You are asking whether the disconnection was immediately before the OnResume? I don't think so. I tested it a lot, and mostly in places with good internet.

Comment: I will check the logcat.

Comment: Ok, please check, and tel me if you get such a message.

Comment: Hi Alex, I checked the logcat and I do infact see this message. I guess it means that the socket is down? I made a test and turned on AirPlane mode, and immediately after turning it off checked if I could recreate the problem, but it actually updated without a lag. So it's hard to say exactly what causes the lag. Is it better to try use a GET() call and not a listener? Maybe just when the app resumes?

Answer (score 0):

According to this question from the comments section:

> Are you getting such a message `Failed to resolve name. status={1}` in the logcat?

And this answer:

> I checked the logcat and I do in fact see this message.

I can tell you that this is happening due to **no** internet connection on the user's device, as between the time when you regain the internet connection and the time when the listener actually becomes active, there is an amount of time in which your client is not connected to the server. That's the reason why that warning is printed out in the logcat. Most likely is printed out multiple times without stopping until the network is back on and the client is synchronized again with the Firebase servers.

The reason that those retries aren't happening so quickly as you expect, and you encounter that lag (60-90 seconds) is because the code that performs the retries is using a so-called [Exponential backoff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). This means that this code prevents all the retries that can happen on the user's device so quickly in favor of performance. Too many retries can also affect the user by consuming too much bandwidth of his data plan. Which indeed is not something you want.

Unfortunately, when you are listening for changes in a Cloud Firestore database and you have some network disconnects, there isn't much you can do. You don't have any control over how Firebase Firestore Android SDK manages its connections.

If you wonder to get rid of that, IMO, since it's only a warning and **not** an Exception, you can simply ignore it. However, I found a way you might solve this:

- [Not receiving document updates on network disconnect and reconnect in Firestore Java admin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313824/not-receiving-document-updates-on-network-disconnect-and-reconnect-in-firestore/53316304)

I have not tested this solution, but you might give it a try.

Comment: 2 questions:  1. if the listener is detached, why does the client still tries to connect to the server? 2. If I do a GET request with source Server, would it work-around this problem?

Comment: If i use the API to disable the network on stop and enable it on resume, can it solve the problem?

Comment: Creating an instance of FirebaseFirestore and listening for real-time updates are two totally different things. If you remove the listener to stop listening for updates, it doesn't mean that the FirebaseFirestore instance is null. If you are using `Source.SERVER` it means that every time you are performing a get() call, you are looking to retrieve data **only** from the server. Furthermore, if you disable the network in onStop it means that any other service that relies on the network will fail. So I'm afraid it's not such a good idea.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for all your efforts with this! I am now in development, and have not yet had the chance to review your answer. I didn't really understand it, and have not yet tested. After I test and see it is working correctly, I can mark the answer is acceptable.

Comment: Ok, no worries, take your time. Try it, and keep me posted. Thanks

Comment: Hey David. Did you found some time to try my solution above?